# String to regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I get regular expression string from server. For example

```
js_pattern = "/^9\d+$/"
```

And I need to get from this string the same regular expression (without any modifications)

```
js_regexp = /^9\d+$/
```

`re = new RegExp(js_pattern)` doesn't work for me because in that case I get `/\/^9d+$\//`

Are there any correct variants to convert string to regular expression in JavaScript?

Comment: How is the stuff getting from the server? AJAX?

Comment: @KevinNagurski, yes, ajax. I get set of rules for different form fields.

Comment: you can't assume whether it's a `d` or `\d`

Comment: The issue is that the `\d` is being evaluated when it is assigned in string form. Your only real option is to escape it from the server-side.

Comment: I can't modify this rule on server-side (backend specificity), I have to validate with this rules and I haven't found any correct variants to do it. And `\d` is a particular case, any rules can come from server. And it seems there is no way to do it correctly, only using some hacks

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
re = new RegExp(js_pattern.slice(1,-1))
```

**UPDATE:**

to satisfy the limit **without any modifications**, here is a way, maybe not the best:

```
eval(js_pattern)
```

but, because '\' is an escape character in JavaScript, you should replace '\' with '\\' at server side.

**UDDATE:**

If you alread received the string as "/^9\d+$/", you need do nothing at the server side.

Comment: looks like the `\d` isn't preserved with that.

Comment: `test` and `exec` aren't available for strings

Answer (score 1):

**Any *non-special* character gets evaluated to just that character in a string**.

For example

```
// true, because it's non-special so it gets evaluated to that character.
console.log("\a" === "a"); // true

// false, because it's the new line special character.
console.log("\n" === "n"); // false
```

[JavaScript special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)

Solution:

Escape the backslashes on the server before you send it over.

Answer (score 0):

This is really dependent on your server-side code, but essentially your problem is that that `\d` is being evaluated in the string as an escaped character. My solution is specific to PHP, but other server-side languages should have similar.

```
// drop the enclosing slashes, either here or in JS land
$jsPattern = addslashes("^9\d+$");
// $jsPattern => "^9\\d+$"
```

Now in the JS side, you can use this:

```
var js_exp = new RegExp(js_pattern);
```

Easiest option is to just remove the enclosing slashes and add an extra escaping slash yourself, if you can.